# SQL Server timestamp column not supported in Mono?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2005, ado.net, mono

I am trying to run a .NET command line application in Linux using Mono.  It accesses SQL Server 2005 Express database and, when querying some data it throws the following exception:

```
System.NotSupportedException: Unknown Type : timestamp
  at Mono.Data.Tds.TdsMetaParameter.GetMetaType () [0x00000] 
  at Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.Tds70.WriteParameterInfo (Mono.Data.Tds.TdsMetaParameter param) [0x00000] 
  at Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.Tds70.ExecRPC (System.String rpcName, Mono.Data.Tds.TdsMetaParameterCollection parameters, Int32 timeout, Boolean wantResults) [0x00000] 
  at Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.Tds70.ExecProc (System.String commandText, Mono.Data.Tds.TdsMetaParameterCollection parameters, Int32 timeout, Boolean wantResults) [0x00000] 
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.Execute (Boolean wantResults) [0x00000] 
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader (CommandBehavior behavior) [0x00000]
```

Queried table has a `RowVersion` column whose type is `timestamp`.  Isn't it possible to use timestamp columns in SQL Server when running .NET applications in Mono?

Comment: Can you post the code where you query the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run your application through [MoMA](http://www.mono-project.com/MoMA) (Mono Migration Analyzer). It should tell you what is and isn't supported by Mono.

**Update:**

Took a look at the [source code](http://anonsvn.mono-project.com/viewvc/trunk/mcs/class/Mono.Data.Tds/Mono.Data.Tds/TdsMetaParameter.cs), where this is thrown (`GetMeteType`, starting on line 334), and indeed `timestamp` is missing from the list of types.

Raise a [bug](http://www.mono-project.com/Bugs).